# Every 5 minutes asyncronously run a group of promises and place all of them into a list for express to display on a webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a project that requires asyncronous querys to servers which at times can fail, I unfortautely have been reading loads of documentation and still haven't come up with a solution to my issue. If an error does occour either as a timeout or otherwise I would like it to place "ERROR" in place of this for the application to process.

I've tried learning promises and get them to a degree but none of the things I learnt seem to work with this use.

```
function serverping(ip, port){
  Gamedig.query({
    type: 'garrysmod',
    host: ip,
    port: port
  }).then((state) => {
    current_state = state
    resolve(current_state)
  }).catch((error) => {
    current_state = "ERROR"
    resolve(current_state)
  });
}

const darkrp = serverping("51.68.195.20", "27015")
//const mrp = serverping("51.68.195.20", "27016")
//const prp = serverping("51.68.195.20", "27017")

Promise.all([darkrp])
  .then(responses => {
    servers = responses
  })

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(servers)
  res.render('index', { drp_status:servers[0],  mrp_status:servers[1],  prp_status:servers[2] })
});
```

The idea is that I keep querying the servers every 300 seconds or so and then when a client connects just use that data to display it. There are multiple servers within this system.

Comment: setTimeout or setInterval seem perfect for this job

Comment: In your code you are querying just one server ... so if I understand you correctly you would like to query all your servers every 300 seconds and the query method (serverping?) should return a promise which resolves either to a success state or to an error state?

Comment: Yeah, if it's sucessful it responds with a object with data within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a solution to this I took [Jaromanda X's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x) Advice and used setInterval then modified how I was handling things, instead of using a function as a promise I created a promise directly with the code then created a function to query all the servers with Promise.all and created a setInterval which runs this function every X amount of time.

```
var darkrp = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  Gamedig.query({
    type: 'garrysmod',
    host: '51.68.195.20',
    port: '27015'
  }).then((state) => {
    current_state = state
    resolve(current_state)
  }).catch((error) => {
    current_state = "ERROR"
    resolve(current_state)
  });
});

var militaryrp = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  Gamedig.query({
    type: 'garrysmod',
    host: '51.68.195.20',
    port: '27016'
  }).then((state) => {
    current_state = state
    resolve(current_state)
  }).catch((error) => {
    current_state = "ERROR"
    resolve(current_state)
  });
});

var policerp = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  Gamedig.query({
    type: 'garrysmod',
    host: '51.68.195.20',
    port: '27017'
  }).then((state) => {
    current_state = state
    resolve(current_state)
  }).catch((error) => {
    current_state = "ERROR"
    resolve(current_state)
  });
});
//const mrp = serverping("51.68.195.20", "27016")
//const prp = serverping("51.68.195.20", "27017")

function query_servers() {
  console.log("Querying Servers...")
  Promise.all([darkrp, militaryrp, policerp])
  .then(responses => {
    servers = responses
    //console.log(servers)
  })
}
setInterval(function(){query_servers()}, 4000);
```